# How to use PostreSQL hstore with nested array in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, hash, hstore

Migration:

```
class Preference < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    enable_extension 'hstore'

    create_table :preferences do |t|
      t.hstore :prefs
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :prefs
end
```

This seems to work if prefs is a hash such as `{ email:'yes' }`, but does not work for a hash with an array inside: `{ email:[ 'monday', 'tuesday' ]}`.

When pulling the hash out, the array is saved as JSON.

Is there a good way to use hstore with nested hashes and arrays?

I did try adding `array:true` to the migration, but this just seemed to allow the saving of an array instead of a hash.

How to use Rails PostgreSQL hstore with nested hashes and arrays?

Rails 4.2.4, PostgreSQL 9.3.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL hstore is intended to store key value pairs of text strings. Take a look at the [hstore docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html).

I've used the JSON type to store arrays as a value inside a hash. There are two JSON data types: JSON and JSONB. JSONB supports indexing but is a little slower whereas JSON does not support indexing but is faster. You can read about them here:  [JSON Type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html).

I would do the following:

```
class Preference < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :preferences do |t|
      t.json :prefs
    end
  end
end
```

On a side note setting `array: true` on the hstore column would imply that you want to store an array of hstores.

Comment: This is the solution I am using now. Works fine, except it seems that it does not support indexes.

Comment: Yeah you are right. There are two JSON data types: json and jsonb.  jsonb supports indexing

Comment: And you need PostgreSQL 9.4 for `jsonb`, no?

Comment: @muistooshort seems like it. The docs i linked to are for 9.4

Answer (score 1):

You could simply parse the JSON on access:

```
class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
  def prefs
    self[:pref] = json_parse_values self[:pref]
  end

  private
  def json_parse_values(hash)
    hash.map do |key, val|
      begin
        [key, (val.is_a?(String) ? JSON.parse(val) : val)]
      rescue JSON::ParserError => e  
        [key, val]
      end 
    end.to_h
  end
end
```

The parsing method attempts to parse a value only if its a string. If it raises a `ParserError`, we just use the string.